# How to split a long string into a multi-line string, but the string is a value inside of a javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, object, multilinestring

I am creating an FAQ page for a site, and instead of statically typing out every question and answer into each component, I decided to create an array of objects with every question and answer inside of it, and then map through the array to make my react code look cleaner.

Some of the answers are paragraphs, but I want to split up some of the paragraphs into multiple smaller paragraphs.

I've tried \n within backticks and \n within single and double quotes but the paragraph does not split up into multiple lines in the browser. Does it have something to do with being inside of an object and that's why it won't add a new line with \n?

**Here is my FAQ object :**

```
export const faqData = [{
     question: "Can we make this product personalized?",
     answer: "Yes, all products can be personalized. Please visit our shop page for 
    all personalized options.\n You can view the shop page here."
},
```

**Here is my component :**

```
import React from "react";
import Title from "./title/Title";
import Questions from "./faqs/Questions";
import { faqData } from "./utils/faqs";

const FAQ = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Div">
      <Title />
      {faqData.map(({ question, answer }) => (
        <Questions question={question} answer={answer} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FAQ;
```

Comment: basically, if you put <pre> or <code> tags around your strings, it will honor the newline characters

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried that and then put in the \n again but it wouldn't recognize the \n. It would simply add the \n as part of the string

Comment: "It would simply add..." If you are seeing the actual \n characters, it just means you haven't encoded the newline character correctly. Get that fixed up and you should be on your way

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we can't see how you're splitting the string in the `Questions` component with your code shown. It should be a fairly simple mapping on the `string.split('\n')`.

In the return of your `Questions` component, it should look something similar to:

```
return (
   <div className="Questions">
      <h2>${props.question}</h2>
      {
         props.answer.split('\n').map((paragraph) => {
            return <p>{paragraph}</p>;
         }
      }
   </div>
)
```

This will break the `answer` into an array of strings split up by `\n`'s, then map it into individual paragraph tags.

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML collapses whitespace. You can change this behaviour with the `white-space` CSS property. In this case, `white-space: pre-line` might be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

For a different solution to display multiline instead of `\n`, you could format your `answer` in HTML (to use `<br />`) and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` ([warning](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml))

```
const faqData = [
  {
    question: "1 Can we make this product personalized?",
    answer: "Yes, all products can be personalized."
  },
  {
    question: "2 Can we make this product personalized?",
    answer:
      "Yes, all products can be personalized. Please visit our shop page for all personalized options.<br /> You can view the shop page here."
  }
];

const Title = () => <h1>FAQ</h1>;

const Questions = ({ question, answer }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{question}</h3>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
  </div>
);
```

Full demo

[image: Edit angry-haibt-z4u9bg]